# Clr namespace mapping to default xaml namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm a bit tired of having to declare an xmlns in every xaml file and having to use prefixes for my custom controls. Is it possible to map a clr namespace to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"?

I tried the following in my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation","MyOwnNamespace")]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I still get a compile error like:

> The tag 'MyCustomControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Note: My controls are within the same assembly (I have a single assembly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Unfortunately, you cannot use controls mapped to a Xaml namespace defined by `XmlnsDefinition`, if the controls are defined in the same assembly. Different assemblies work fine though. You'll have to use the `clr-namespace` definition for this.
2. Why would you want to add your controls to the Xaml default namespace? Don't do this. It's like using the `System` namespace for your classes because you don't want to add `using` directives for their namespaces.

Comment: Well, if I had to put "local:" in front of every variable that references my classes, and not were able to add the `using` so simply (thanks to VS resolve->add using...), then I'd also be asking you how I can include my classes in the System namespace :)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez ok, Xaml certainly isn't as user-friendly as the C# editor :) Is using a shorter prefix than `local:` not an option? I know i have been doing this at some point and used `l:` instead because that long prefix looked ugly.

Comment: Yes, `l:` would be more convenient than `local:` for sure. I might use that. Thanks.

Comment: I'd agree on #2 as a best practice, but depending how you're feeling, you wouldn't have to use any `xmlns` declarations on your controls if you do that.  Personal opinion but just makes it transparent from which namespace controls are being referenced from.